# How to check a radio button with angularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I am creating a html / angularjs form. In the form i have a radio button with yes or no. So i want to check by default the button No.
This is the code i use : 
My controller :

```
angular.module('radioExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.myvariable = 'false';

    }]);
```

My html code snippet:

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="radio" id="variable" name="variable" ng-model="myvariable" value="true">Yes</input> 
                <input type="radio" id="variable" name="variable" ng-model="myvariable" value="false">No</input>
            </div>
```

But nothing is selected(checked) when i load the form the first time. I have to click to one value to have one selected (checked)
What's wrong with my code ? Here the [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/cjxnwAe9wxDkzSoLSB3Z?p=preview)
Thanks

Comment: add ng-app="radioExample" on your html. Basically angular is not bootstrapped...

Comment: i add it. It' does not correct the problem.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/soKwoChH14ttlBlhGZB6?p=preview here I added ng-app you can take a look

Answer (score 0):

I've made a `fiddle` for you. Check [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/g8kyJ/18/)

You should also set `ng-value` which should be `true` or `false`

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="o in options">
        <input type="radio" name="group1" ng-model="o.checked" ng-value="o.checked"></input>
        <label>{{o.name}}</label>
    </div>
</div>



var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.options =  [
       { name: 'OPT1', id: 1, checked: false },
       { name: 'OPT2',id: 2, checked: false },
       { name: 'OPT3',id: 3, checked: true  }
    ];
   }
```

Comment: i cannot access to fiddle just plunker. I am behind a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it does not work in your plunkr is because you create a module named "radioExample" but you don't use it when you write the HTML code.

Basically, replace this -

```
<html ng-app>
```

at the beginning of the code with this

```
<html ng-app="radioExample">
```

This way, when you declare the controller, AngularJS knows which module it needs to look into to get the controller.

Note - if you had not associated your controller with a module, then your code would work.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `ng-checked`. What you have to do is to add `ng-app="radioExample"` to the `html`-Tag of your Application.

Then add `ng-checked="myvariable == 'false'"` and `ng-value="'value'"` like in the following plunker example:
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CaEqpDM5cj9Ab6PzUu5B?p=preview)

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <input ng-checked="myvariable == 'true'" type="radio" id="variable" name="variable" ng-model="myvariable" value="true">Yes
    <input ng-checked="myvariable == 'false'" type="radio" id="variable" name="variable" ng-model="myvariable" value="false">No
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Error in data binding. Define myvariable in controller override value in radiobutton. You must use ng-repeat like

```
<div ng-repeat="o in options">
    <input type="radio" name="name" ng-model="o.checked" ng-value="o.checked"></input>
    <label>{{o.name}}</label>
</div>
```

(I use code from previous answer)